# How to mock a task from a dependency called from an external consumer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I'm a newbie in mocking and was asked to build some unit tests for a method, what I understood so far is that one dependency of this class (where the method to be tested is located) waits for a consumer to call a task<> and the method assigns some work to do for it.

Class to be tested - method StartProcess

```
public class MessageProcessor
{
    private readonly IMessageReceiver _receiver;

    public MessageProcessor(IMessageReceiver receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public async void StartProcess(Func<string, string, Task<bool>> funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller)
    {
        await _receiver.OnMessageReceived<object>("string param", async (messageReceived, cancelationToken) =>
        {
            // Some validations to the messageReceived object
            var callerParam1 = string.Empty;
            var callerParam2 = string.Empty;
            var result = await funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller(callerParam1, callerParam2);
            // validate result and do some more work            
        });
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to build some unit tests where the StartProcess method is called and the OnMessageReceived task can be also be called with different data, as I dont have access to the dll where the funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller code is being executed it would be nice if I can write a custom method to be executed in my tests or just return directly a custom Result object.

For this I'm using MSTest and Moq.

Unfortunatelly Im very lost as I have no previous experience on mocking. this is what I have done so far

```
[TestClass()]
public class MessageProcessorTest
{
    private Mock<IMessageReceiver> receiverMock = null!;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        receiverMock = new Mock<IMessageReceiver>();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public async Task On_Received_Message()
    {            
        receiverMock.Setup(o => o.OnMessageReceived(“some string Param”, It.IsAny<DataObject>())).Returns(Task.Run(() => {  }));
        consumer = new MessageProcessor(receiverMock.Object);
        
        try
        {       
            consumer.StartProcess(...) //No idea how to execute it here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail("No exception expected: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Param1` and `Param2` and is there an implicit conversion from `string` to those types? What is `stringParam`? The question isn't too big, so good job on that, but please edit it so that it's also [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann those are just primitive types, I already edited it to be more clear. thx

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, tricky. While you can test this with Moq, I think that using a [Test Spy](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Spy.html) is neater, so I provide both alternatives.

I've taken the liberty to write the tests in [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net/) instead of MSTest, but I trust you can replace the `[Fact]` attribute with `[TestMethod]`.

## Moq-based test

Here's a way to do it with Moq:

```
[Fact]
public void OnMessageReceivedMock()
{
    var receiverMock = new Mock<IMessageReceiver>();
    receiverMock
        .Setup(r => r.OnMessageReceived<object>(
            "string param",
            It.IsAny<Func<object, CancellationToken, Task>>()))
        .Callback<string, Func<object, CancellationToken, Task>>(
            async (stringParam, f) =>
                await f("messageReceived", new CancellationToken()))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
        .Verifiable();
    var sut = new MessageProcessor(receiverMock.Object);

    sut.StartProcess(
        async (callerParam1, callerParam2) =>
        {
            Assert.Equal("", callerParam1);
            Assert.Equal("", callerParam2);
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        });

    receiverMock.Verify();
}
```

Really tricky. I had to first `Setup` the `receiverMock` - not because the test really needs to set up a return value, but because that's the only way to gain access to the `Callback` method.

Moq will call the expression you supply to `Callback` every time the `Setup` is matched. In that call-back the test then invokes the `f` function - that's the `funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller`. If the `MessageProcessor` is correctly implemented, the anonymous code block with assertions will then run, and verify that the arguments are as they are supposed to be.

The test then invokes `StartProcess` and finally `receiverMock.Verify()`. Because the `Setup` pipeline ends with `Verifiable()` the test doesn't have to repeat the expression that's already in the `Setup`; `Verify()` is enough.

## Spy-based test

In my opinion, using Moq in this way is far too complicated, so I'd like to suggest a simpler alternative, based on a Test Spy.

First, define a Test Spy in your test code:

```
internal sealed class SpyMessageReceiver :
    Collection<(string, Func<object, CancellationToken, Task>)>,
    IMessageReceiver
{
    public Task OnMessageReceived<T>(
        string stringParam,
        Func<object, CancellationToken, Task> value)
    {
        Add((stringParam, value));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This is just a class that inherits from a collection base class and also implements the `IMessageReceiver`. Every time someone calls `OnMessageReceived`, the Spy just uses the base class' `Add` method to save the call parameters for later.

With that in place, the test perhaps still takes a bit of time to wrap your head around, but at least looks fairly pretty:

```
[Fact]
public async Task OnMessageReceivedSpy()
{
    var receiverSpy = new SpyMessageReceiver();
    var sut = new MessageProcessor(receiverSpy);

    sut.StartProcess(
        async (callerParam1, callerParam2) =>
        {
            Assert.Equal("", callerParam1);
            Assert.Equal("", callerParam2);
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        });

    var (sp, f) = Assert.Single(receiverSpy);
    Assert.Equal("string param", sp);
    await f("messageReceived", new CancellationToken());
}
```

Notice that we pass an anonymous code block to `StartProcess` - it plays the role of `funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller`. Inside of that code block are a few assertions, since I'm assuming that what you really want to verify is that `funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller` gets called with the correct arguments.

At this point, however, `funcToBeExecutedInTheCaller` has not been called. It only runs once the `_receiver` decides to run it.

Good thing that we have the spy.

First, we assert that `receiverSpy` actually has a set of arguments, which implies that `OnMessageReceived` was called. (IIRC, I'm not sure that MSTest has something similar to `Assert.Single` - if not, you'll have to first assert that the `receiverSpy` contains a single value, and then extract that value.)

For good measure, the test first verifies that `OnMessageReceived` was called with `"string param"` - I don't know, but it might be important.

Finally, the test calls the function that the spy recorded. This then runs the anonymous code block, which then runs the assertions.

## Concluding remarks

Importantly, I've seen both tests fail by either changing the assertions or sabotaging the `StartProcess` implementation. This is important because it tells me that the tests actually discover errors in the System Under Test (SUT).

While I prefer the Spy-based test, I still think it's too complicated. I know that this isn't test-driven development (TDD), but rather test-after, but an important lesson from TDD is that tests tell you how easy it is for client code to *use* the SUT.

That lesson about API design feedback is also true for tests written after the implementation code. Both of these tests are, in my opinion, far too complicated. I would take that as a strong suggestion to make the API simpler.

Finally, unless you absolutely *must* use it, [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).